# Composer error [UnexpectedValueException]

Tags: php, composer-php

I tried composer install and got the following error. Anyone know what it means?

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   Could not parse version constraint Needed: Invalid version string
>   "Needed"
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader]
>   [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

All my composer.json has in it is this:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
    "league/oauth2-client": "Needed for Gmail's XOAUTH2 authentication system"
  }
}
```

Comment: `"league/oauth2-client": "Needed for Gmail's XOAUTH2 authentication system"` .. this is the culprit , you should have `"league/oauth2-client" : "1.10"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not parse version constraint Needed: Invalid version string
>   "Needed"

You need a package version number and not the string 'Needed for Gmail's XOAUTH2 authentication system'.

For example:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
    "league/oauth2-client": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```